# C# Convert string to ITcAdsSymbol datatype

Tags: c#, twincat-ads

Question: I have a datatype that is non standard in C#. So the standard Convert. functions in Visual Studio do not apply to this type. How can I convert a string to this datatype?

I'm trying to simulate a analog input via an ADS protocol using TwinCAT.

In order to do this I have in C# a text box. I'd like to convert the input of the text box from string to "ITcAdsSymbol" datatype. (This is a datatype that comes with the ADS protocol)

Unfortunatly I don't know how to convert this to ITcAdsSymbol. I have tried the following lines but they dit not work:

ITcAdsSymbol temp = Convert.ToITcAdsSymbol((string)textBox1.Text);

ITcAdsSymbol temp = Convert.ITcAdsSymbol((string)textBox1.Text);

ITcAdsSymbol temp = Convert.ToSymbol((string)textBox1.Text);

I can simulate digital inputs using the following code in C#:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private TcAdsClient ads = new TcAdsClient();
    private int DigIn1;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ads.Connect(851);
        if(ads.IsConnected==true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection OK");
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection failed");
        }
        DigIn1 = ads.CreateVariableHandle("DigitalInputs.DigitalIn_1_1");
        
    }
    

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ads.WriteAny(DigIn1, true);
        

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ads.WriteAny(DigIn1, false);
    
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly this is only able to send either a logic 0 or a 1

Other solutions are also welcome. As long as I can simulate an analog input.

Many Thanks, Roy

Comment: Is there any vendor documentation you can share about ITcAdsSymbol? Also, I'm not sure why/how you would convert string data into a custom data type. If ITcAdsSymbol is an object, can you just assign the string to any ofyour ads objects properties? Does the constructor of ITcAdsSymbol have any overrides and do any of them take in a string?

Comment: Actually, so found some vendor documentation online. ITcAdSymbol is an interface - so your question about type conversion doesn't really make sense. Do you possibly mean TcAdsClient instead? If so, what is being put into the text (what does it represent) and why do you want to feed it to your object?

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/index.php?content=../content/1031/tcadsnetref/7313546379.html&id=

Comment: @hallibut Im able to read out an analog output via the following code: 

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
private ITcAdsSymbol AnaOut1 = null; 
private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AnaOut1 = ads.ReadSymbolInfo("AnalogOutputs.AnalogOut_1_1");
            int ConOut1 = Convert.ToInt32(ads.ReadSymbol(AnaOut1));
            textBox2.Text = ConOut1.ToString();
        }
}

(1/2)

Comment: (2/2) This works. So I can read the value of an variable from TwinCAT into C#. Now I'm trying to write an value to a variable in TwinCAT, so the opposite way. I kind of assumed that this would work similar to the code I posted above. What would be a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: The value that I'm trying to write from C# into TwinCAT represents an input of an analogue in of a PLC. The input of the PLC is a word type so 0 = 0% and 65535 = 100%

Comment: I've worked a bit with industrial automation and manufacturing equipment, but haven't really ever worked with this API, so my suggestions aren't based on experience but inference. Reading through the vendor documentation (looking at the methods available to TcAdClient) it seems like there's some conversion TcAdClient is capable of. You may need to call one of those methods prior. However, I also found this read/write example in their documentation. I wonder if any of these help:

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/index.php?content=../content/1031/tcadsnetref/7313546379.html&id=

Comment: Sorry, it keeps relinking to my first link. There is a section in the index of TwinCat.ADS .Net Komponente>>TwinCAT ADS .NET v4>>... titled How/To Samples with examples of both read and write for TcAdsClient

Comment: No worries, the link worked. I think I found the solution https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcadsnetref/7312586891.html&id=

Comment: It's working! You indeed don't have to tamper with converting values. Just declare a int var and put the value you want to sent in there. Then use: ads.WriteSmbol("POU_name.Input_name", var, false);